# ID is NULL in Gridview when image Button Clicked.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am displaying all of the registered user in GridView from a DB, along with an Image Button. But while clicking on the button ID is NULL.
how ever i have bind ID with DataKey.

Comment: what you are using foe add? i can help if i  its a link button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will typically embed an image into the cell on the server side and pass the id in the javascript call.  Then on the client side you handle the click event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var data = (DataService.User)e.Row.DataItem;
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = string.Format(@"<img src='images/friend.png' onclick='javascript:ShowDetails(""{0}"")' />", data.UserID);
        }
    }
```

On the client side you handle the click event and you have the id of the image that was clicked.

```
function ShowDetails(id) {
    ...
}
```

you can do this with just about any control.  place a checkbox or link or image or anything into a cell this way.